# Check out page redirects to shopping cart again and again

Tags: php, checkout, cart

After adding items to cart when customer going to checkout, at first step of billing info, when we click continue, customer is redirected back to shopping cart and not on next step.
Please help to resolve this issue..

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Please enable *System* and *Exception* Log so you will check exact issue.

1. Log into your Magento Admin Backend.
2. Go to *System > Configuration*.
3. Click on *Developer* in the left side menu pane.
4. Open the *Log Settings* section.
5. Change the *Enabled* to *Yes*
6. Click *Save Config*

`system.log` and `exception.log` files are located in the `/var/log` folder

Answer (score 0):

Seems some error in ajax call `saveBillingAction` in `OnepageController`. Quick way is to see in console. You can see the error in firebug console onclick continue.

That error you can update in your question. Based on that we can help.

**Possible reason:** You are using some custom checkout extension.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your theme contains the updated files which have form_key defined